# "The value for the useBean class attribute user.UserData is invalid" - why?

Tags: java, forms, jsp

Attempting to create a selection of webpages that take some information, and then display it on a later page, Works up to the retrieving and displaying stage, where I get the following error,

> The value for the useBean class attribute user.UserData is invalid

I am using the following tutorial: http://www.jsptut.com/Forms.jsp

I know there is probably 40 billion different questions aanswering this, but I literally picked up JSP at 9.13am this morning. So I need a tailormade answer!

I'm using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat 6.0.33

Thanks

P.S. Some google research keeps mentioning compile.class. Some mention they compiled the bean, but it thought JavaScript was a script meaning it didn't need to be compiled?

Rev: Right, so apparently, i need to compile the bean and then use JSP to execute it? Can anybody advise me on how to compile my Bean?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript, I've fixed the tags and title for you. It's a Java question. (Java and JavaScript are effectively unrelated, they just have similar names and both use syntax derived from B, like C, C++, C#, and many other languages do.)

Comment: Oh, The tutorial i used lead me to believe it was JavaScript. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you compile the user bean and put it in the classpath as the tutorial instructs?

Comment: (The tutorial does state you should be able to program in Java; can you?)

Comment: No, I literally came across it by Searching 'Display HTML Form Data' Could anybody point me towards how to compile the bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ is a good place to start. You might want to jump into http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html. It's a step-by-step on how to write, compile and run using command-line tools and then work your way down the tutorial list.

When you're a little familiar with that, you can set yourself up with a good development environment, like [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org)